# Filter duplicate values in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-query-language

I have the following table:

[example]

[image: 1]

How can I make a new table where all the duplicates are merged and the values are added together so I have a total per name ?

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(V:X; "select V,sum(W),sum(X) where V is not null group by V")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name    value
A   34
B   25
A   18
C   14
B   16
A   9
B   4
C   9

name    value
A   61
B   45
C   23
```

A:

```
SELECT name, SUM(value)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY name
```